# Gets function is undefined

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2015, undefined

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I want to write a code regarding files in C language. I want to get a name from the keyboard (and then put this name in the file) and I am using the function gets. But it doesn't work, the compiler says ,,gets is undefined". 
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: 1.) Be aware, gets() is [deprecated](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/gets.html)

Comment: From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2029ea5f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):    "These functions are obsolete. Beginning in Visual Studio 2015, they are not available in the CRT. The secure versions of these functions, gets_s and _getws_s, are still available."

Comment: `gets` isn't just deprecated. As of C11 the deprecation ran out. It is completely *eliminated* from the standard library. Any toolchain half-attempting to comply with the C11 standard should no longer offer its services (as you're seeing).

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed.  Per paragraph 6 of the **Foreward**:  *- removed the `gets` function (`<stdio.h>`)* (top of page xiv, C Standard link:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Two more points: (1) Whatever book or tutorial or greybeard instructor it was who told you about `gets` in the first place is seriously out-of-date, and you will want to view any other teachings of theirs with suspicion. (2) Your next question, after switching to `fgets`, is likely to be, "But what abut the newline?"  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Answer (score 2):

The comments have pointed out that `gets` is taken out completely. The reason is that `gets` can easily cause [`buffer overflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

You are supposed to use `fgets` instead since you can limit the input to the size of your buffer.